# Is this if statement correct, or is it redundant?

Tags: objective-c

I've a simple question about if statement in Objective - C.

Is this if statement correct, or is it redundant and I don't need to specify ==YES ?

```
NSNumber *boolean = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
if (boolean == YES) ...
```

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You compare pointer and integer, which won't lead you to the result you want.

Example:

```
NSNumber *boolean1 = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
if (boolean1) {
    // true
}

NSNumber *boolean2 = [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO];
if (boolean2) {
    // this is also true
}

if ([boolean1 boolValue] && ![boolean2 boolValue]) {
    // true
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No, it isn't correct and it isn't going to generate the output you think it is. `NSNumber * boolean` is a pointer to an object in memory while `YES` is a scalar value; they should not be compared with `==`.

If you type this code you'll also get the following warning:

[image: warning from comparison]

The correct way to do it would be:

```
NSNumber *boolean = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
if ( [boolean boolValue] ) {
  // do something
}
```

But this statement itself does not make much sense, since you should be comparing the `BOOL`s and not `NSNumber` -- there is no need to use the `NSNumber` in there.

Answer (score 0):

This won't work. An instance of `NSBoolean` is an object, and will be non-NULL whether YES or NO.

There's two good ways to check the value of a `NSBoolean`.

The first is to use `boolValue`:

```
NSNumber *boolean = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
if ([boolean boolValue] == YES) ...
if ([boolean boolValue]) ... // simpler
```

The second is to use the identity of the object returned:

```
NSNumber *boolean = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
if (boolean == (id)kCFBooleanTrue) ...
```

The latter is faster; it relies on there being only one each of `NSBoolean YES` and `NSBoolean NO` on the system. These have the same values as `kCFBooleanTrue` and `kCFBooleanFalse`. I've read this is safe forever, but I'm not sure it's part of Apple's published documentation.